# WPF datagrid control

Tags: wpf, datagrid

what to do if data grid control was not available in WPF component visual studio 2008

i ll try to add control from wpf component but there are no data grid control available in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `WPF 3.5`, you need to install [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) to get DataGrid control.

However, with `WPF 4.0`, microsoft introduce DataGrid under `System.Windows.Controls (PresentationFramework.dll)` assembly so that it can be used just like other controls without referring to WPFToolkit.